# Comedy-Horror movie about an apocalyptic world

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this movie last year on T.V. English, in colour.

- There were three people, two males and a woman. One man and the woman were both scientists.
- They seem to be out at an amusement when they fall into some gorge.
- Moments later, they are transported to some futuristic place.
- They discover that the place is an absolute desert.
- A few minutes, in, they spot some ape-like organisms trying to kill one another.
- The non-scientist scares them away and rescues one of them.
- The creature and the gang become friends, though the male scientist is not too keen.
- The woman seems to speak an ape-like language, and thus helps the gang communicate.
- They are chased by a dinosaur into a cave, where they stay for the night.
- The next day, they find some beautiful structures out there in the forested parts and eventually come into contact with some creature (who speaks English).
- The newly-met tells the gang that he has been imprisoned here and needs help from them; he needs to find some powerful device. He also promises to return the gang home using it.
- They then set out in search of this particular device.
- Once they find the device and return it to the creature, they are immediately betrayed. I cannot remember how.
- In the end, they all do get home, however.

Any guesses?

Comment: It wasn't animated, no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [Land of the Lost (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457400/), starring Will Ferrell.

From IMDb synopsis: "On his latest expedition, Dr. Rick Marshall is sucked into a space-time vortex alongside his research assistant and a redneck survivalist. In this alternate universe, the trio make friends with a primate named Chaka, their only ally in a world full of dinosaurs and other fantastic creatures."

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds exactly right, only in a scene right at the end they don't all get home (good scene)

Comment: Yep, this is it.